# Performance curiosity on pandas series `any`, `max`, `sum` vs python builtins

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, built-in

Seeking performance in python applications using pandas/numpy often benefits from the use of the pandas/numpy implemented methods other than own implemented code such as through looping. This might be a bad introduction to the question I have, but in the following screenshot (if I hadn't tested it) I was expecting the versions using the series' methods to run faster than the python builtins. Since that's not the case, it means I built a false intuition on this example, but I could not yet find the reason for this. So the question is, why in this case the use of the python builtins has higher performance than the methods applied on the series (am I missing something else?)?

[image]

Comment: Did you verify that they actually do the same thing?

Comment: The output is the same. At least for the tested ones. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Can you test for larger values and also randomise? To see if the result is consistent. 100 values are small enough to fit into cache and since the values are also inline BP could make a difference.

Comment: So for `s=pd.Series([False] * 1_000_000 + [True]*1_000_000)` I see that the run time between both variations is pretty comparable. So is this some overhead of the pandas implementation that is more noticeable for smaller datasets?

Comment: Can you also randomise?

Comment: I used `random.shuffle` to shuffle the list parsed for the instantiation of the series I previously referred in the comment and timed the execution of `any`. The built-in version took 1.8us and the series method 40us, so once again the builtin got faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has its own functions which are **way** different than Python's built in functions, therefore if you call `Series.max()` you are in fact calling [`nanops._nanminmax()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1cbf344fa7b33641c516c5566dd281e8e2ac0170/pandas/core/nanops.py#L988) which is added via the [`IndexOpsMixin`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1cbf344fa7b33641c516c5566dd281e8e2ac0170/pandas/core/base.py#L584) instead of [`builtins.max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Each behave differently, thus have different performance times.

Similarly for the rest of the methods. If you are curious, check the source code for [`Series`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1cbf344fa7b33641c516c5566dd281e8e2ac0170/pandas/core/series.py#L191) class and classes it inherits from for the exact differences between builtin functions and Pandas' implementation.

Answer (score 2):

*am I missing something else?*

You assumed that you always will get same result, which is not true. Example showing different output for `sum` and `pandas.Series.sum` is

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1.0,2.0,float("nan")])
print(s.sum())
print(sum(s))
```

output

```
3.0
nan
```